# Which design-patterns is Koa framework built upon?

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, koa

I was reading Addy Osmani's book [Learning Javascript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book), which I think is a great book on design patterns. When I came upon the *Flyweight* design pattern, I found it pretty familiar. It seemed like I've seen this pattern getting used in any project.

The project I was thinking about was [node-oidc provider](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider), an oidc-provider package written in node.js using [Koa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa) framework.

In the package, an `instance` constant is created which embodies properties and methods to it and is shared all across the application. The `instance` is created using `WeakMap` collection in file [weak_cache.js](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/master/lib//helpers/weak_cache.js) and is first imported into the file [provider.js](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/master/lib/provider.js#L12).

Now, why I think this is very much similar to *flyweight* design pattern is because of the statements in the [pattern's description](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailflyweight).

> It aims to minimize the use of memory in an application by sharing as much data as possible with related objects (e.g application configuration, state and so on).

> In practice, Flyweight data sharing can involve taking several similar objects or data constructs used by a number of objects and placing this data into a single external object.

Albeit, I understand it isn't exactly *flyweight* pattern(and I might be wrong on this), but the `instance` constant pretty much resembles the external object in the above statements.

Upon further speculations, I started to think about what other patterns are involved in a simple Koa application. Though the application built on top of Koa will use its own design patterns, but for simplicity & brevity let's consider a simple Koa application as our model for this question.

The key statements in Koa documentation which I think may help us in understanding the design patterns employed are:

> A Koa application is an object containing an array of middleware functions which are composed and executed in a stack-like manner upon request.

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
http.createServer(app.callback()).listen(3000);
https.createServer(app.callback()).listen(3001);
```

From the use of `new` operator, one can think of *Constructor* pattern. All the imported packages tell us the usage of the `Module` pattern.

I know the question is too broad and might be subjective in nature, but I'm trying to see the practical use-cases/scenarios of the patterns I studied in the book.

Comment: Having same question ☺️